# В чем отличие методов, которые назначаются с помощью объектного литерала, и методов, которые назначаются с помощью прототипа (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript

Язык JavaScript
Допустим, есть функция и назначенные методы, одна через прототип:

```js
function User(name, lastname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname  = lastname;
}

User.prototype.getFullName = function () {
    console.log(
        'Полное имя ' + this.name + ' ' + this.lastname
    )
}
```

Плюс, мы внутри функции ещё назначим метод

```
this.getHello = function() {
  console.log('Hello');
}
```

В итоге, мы получим один метод в функции и один метод в прототипе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И, собственно, сам вопрос: в чем принципиальная разница создания методов, в каких случаях нужно назначать через прототип, а в каких случаях лучше в фигурных скобках при определении функции

Comment: Для функций и классов, которыми мы можем управлять и менять, разницы нет.

Comment: цель вопроса разобраться в разнице, если можете расскажите в чём разница вне конеткста функций и классов, ведь для чего то это всё существует в JS